# DLL CreateThread, DisableThreadLibraryCalls and _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to understand what the difference is between `CreateThread` and `_beginthreadex` and why calling `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` only prevents threads installed with `_beginthreadex` from executing.

I have a project which is a DLL, an old DLL, this is a win32 dll and I am tasked with porting it to win64.  One thing that tripped me up was a call in `DLLMain` to `DisableThreadLibraryCalls`.

My threads were installed with `_beginthreadex`, the body of the threads was never being executed cause of the call to `DisableThreadLibraryCalls`.  Once I removed this, the threads were working correctly.

Now I've found that other threads in the same DLL are started with `CreateThread`, I then thought was the call to `DisableThreadLibraryCalls` there to prevent these threads from executing so I put it back and found that the threads created with `CreateThread` are executed regardless of if `DisableThreadLibraryCall`s is present or not but threads created with `_beginthreadex` are disabled.

Why?  I can't find anything on:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682579(v=vs.85).aspx

That describes why this is happening.

Comment: To understand this, you need to look at how the parts of the C++ RTL that implements `_beginthreadex` deals with the thread start/stop notifications that are disabled by `DisableThreadLibraryCalls`.

Comment: I would have thought the documentation on DisableThreadLibraryCalls would have detailed why it doesn't actually effect threads created with CreateThread ?

Comment: beginthreadex() was a CRT function from old versions of the MSVCRT.  It was necessary because the CRT uses thread-local state to make itself thread-safe and they did not know yet how to initialize it correctly.  A primary use for DllMain is to initialize thread-local state.  They had to fix this, Windows 2000 added support for IOCP and a threadpool built into the OS, no way to call beginthreadex for a thread in that pool.  So CreateThread today is just fine.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have found references online that state that `_beginthread` and `_beginthreadex` interally call `CreateThread` so perhaps the checking disable/enable status is only performed in the top level routines which does echo my findings and to me suggests missing logic in `CreateThread`.

`DisableThreadLibaryCalls` has no effect on threads created with `CreateThread` directly.

Answer (score 3):

`CreateThread()` is a Windows native API for creating threads while `_beginthread()` and `_beginthreadex()` are part of C runtime library and are intended to make it easier to manage thread creation, but they still internally have to call `CreateThread()`.

Your own answer is wrong because there is no explicit checking for enable/disable involved in C runtime.

Instead, C runtime library uses `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` and `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` callbacks to manage thread local storage so it should not be surprising that disabling those callbacks by calling `DisableThreadLibraryCalls()` is preventing C runtime thread management functions from working correctly.

Comment: Is there any function or way to achieve similar to functionality DisableThreadLibraryCalls like on Linux